# How to discard a part of a MP4 with ffmpeg

Tags: macos, command-line, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

Is there a way to slice out a 5 minute portion of an MP4 file with ffmpeg?

My attempt at running the following gives me the section I want to *remove* in `hateley2.mp4`.

`ffmpeg -ss 01:02:00.000 -i hateley.mp4 -t 00:05:00.000 -c copy hateley2.mp4`

Is there a way I can turn `hateley2.mp4` into `hateley.mp4` without that 5 minute section from 1hr 2min that I wish to remove?

Comment: What's your tolerance for keeping a part of the 5 minute portion at both ends or removing a bit extra?

Answer (score 1):

There probably is a 1-step `ffmpeg` command to do this, but I always approach it like this:

1. Perform an extract operation like you're doing, but extract from the original, starting at time 0:00 and up to 1:02:00.
2. Perform another extract operation, starting at 1:07:00 thru the end of the film (I think you just leave the duration off to get thru the end).
3. Merge the 2 pieces together like the following:

Merge example:

```
echo 1.mp4 > merge.txt
echo 2.mp4 >> merge.txt
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i merge.txt -c copy merged.mp4
```

If you have more than one audio track in the file(s), you might need a more complicated merge like:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i merge.txt -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c copy merged.mp4
```

Comment: @crmpicco, did this help?